# How to Disabled Collpasible From submenu class Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, collapsable

I have bootstrap script like this

```
 <script>
  $(".submenu > li > a.menu").on("click",function(e){
        var current=$(this).next();
        current.toggle();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(".submenu > a.menu").on("click", function(e){
        var parent = $(this).parent('.submenu');
        parent.toggleClass('open');
    });
    $(".submenu > a").on("click",function(e){
        $(".submenu").removeClass('open');
    });
</script>


<li class="submenu"> <a href="#"><i class="icon icon-signal"></i> <span>Chart</span> 
       <!--<span class="label label-important">3</span>--></a>
     <!--  <a class="trigger">drop 1<span class="ion-ios7-arrow-right submenu-arrow"></span></a>-->
      <ul>
        <li><a class='menu' href='?IDNE=all'>Request Software / Department</a></li>
    <li><a class='menu' href='?IDNE=rnd'>RND</a></li>
    <li><a class='menu' href='?IDNE=maint'>MAINTENANCE</a></li>
    <li><a href='?IDNE=sales_log'>SALES LOGISTIC</a></li>
    <li><a href='?IDNE=hr_sales'>HR SALES</a></li>

      </ul>
    </li>
```

Its work, but after click link inside Submenu, it will collapse. 
What I need is i can stop the collap when My link is active.

How Can I do That?

Any one can fix this?

thanks in advance

[image: After Click the Link, it will collpse.]

Answer (score 0):

I have Found it.

it very simple,

only add open class after submenu

```
<li class="submenu open">
```

and it Open.